# Get href value inside HTML using Groovy

Tags: json, groovy, html-parsing, xmlslurper

I have JSON response in which there is HTML page. I want to get `href` value inside HTML page.

JSON Response

```json
    {
       "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('fbd22ce4-XXXX-4d87-XXXX-6c74983b96fa')/messages(body)",
       "value": [   {
          "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADuJXXX2LXBOZirXXXAAId0Uh\"",
          "id": "AAMkADk0ZGFihiMTIyZmJlYQBGAAAAAACOeACKvLOwQqTkIvTYg8kAAAAAAEMAA8kAAAIebouAAA=",
          "body":       {
             "contentType": "html",
             "content": "<html><head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"><\/head><body><link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@400;600&amp;display=swap\"><table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" style=\"width:100%; border-collapse:collapse; padding:0; margin:0\"><tbody><tr><td><div align=\"center\"><table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" style=\"background-color:white; width:100%; border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; max-width:600pt\"><tbody><tr><td style=\"padding:30pt 33pt\"><span style=\"display:none\">Hello<\/span> <div style=\"border-bottom:1pt solid rgb(231,231,231); vertical-align:middle; padding-bottom:21pt\"><img src=\"https://abc.xyz.com/_images/roomfinder_icon64.png\" alt=\"logo\" style=\"width:28pt; height:30pt; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle\"> <span style=\"vertical-align:middle; display:inline-block; font-family:'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif; font-weight:600; color:rgb(87,107,118); font-size:22pt; line-height:30pt; margin-left:6pt\">Demo<\/span> <\/div><div style=\"font-family:'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif; font-weight:600; font-size:32pt; line-height:36pt; color:rgb(39,39,39); margin-top:26pt; margin-bottom:8pt\">Hello<\/div><div style=\"font-family:'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif; font-weight:400; font-size:16pt; line-height:22pt; color:rgb(87,107,118); margin-bottom:16pt\">Log in to Condeco by pressing the button below on your mobile device.<\/div><div style=\"margin-bottom:15pt\"><div style=\"font-family:'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif; font-weight:400; font-size:18pt; line-height:36pt; letter-spacing:-0.5pt\"><a href=\"https://abc.xyz123.com?key=GBsG3gBoI4YV+fSfejXCbw6vgG6m4OCU7Czfn3PAKXtxVI9Ex\" style=\"font-family:'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif; font-weight:400; font-size:18pt; line-height:36pt; letter-spacing:-0.5pt; background-color:rgb(0,183,241); border-radius:6pt; color:rgb(255,255,255); display:inline-block; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; width:97pt\">Log me in<\/a> <\/div><\/div><div style=\"font-family:'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif; font-weight:400; font-size:14pt; line-height:22pt; color:rgb(87,107,118); margin-bottom:45pt\">This link will expire in 15 minutes.<\/div><div style=\"font-family:'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif; font-weight:600; font-size:20pt; line-height:22pt; color:rgb(39,39,39); margin-bottom:8pt\">On your desktop?<\/div><div style=\"font-family:'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif; font-weight:400; font-size:16pt; line-height:22pt; color:rgb(87,107,118); margin-top:6pt; margin-bottom:8pt\">You can also log in by scanning the QR code below in the app.<\/div><div style=\"margin-bottom:8pt\"><img alt=\"QR Code\" height=\"136\" width=\"136\" src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGzqP1BODMzMzMz86j9QTgzMzMzM/Oo/UE4MzMzMzPzqP1BODMzMzMz86j9QTgzMzMzM/Oo/UE4MzMzMzPzqP1BODMzMzMz86uDcGZmZmZm5lH7g3BmZmZmZuZR+4NwZmZmZmbmUfuDcGZmZmZm5lH7g3BmZmZmZuZR+4NwZmZmZmbmUfuDcGZmZmZm5kn/93//D/OYHJISst1mAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC\" style=\"width:136pt; height:136pt\"><\/div><div style=\"font-family:'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif; font-weight:400; font-size:14pt; line-height:22pt; color:rgb(87,107,118); margin-bottom:46pt\">This QR code will expire in 15 minutes.<\/div><div style=\"font-family:'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif; font-weight:400; font-size:14pt; line-height:22pt; color:rgb(87,107,118); padding-top:15pt; border-top:1pt solid rgb(231,231,231); margin-bottom:15pt\">This email is sent from an unmonitored account - do not reply.<\/div><div><img src=\"https://abc.xyz.com/_images/login/logo-color.png\" alt=\"logo\" style=\"width:113pt; height:31pt\"><\/div><\/td><\/tr><\/tbody><\/table><\/div><\/td><\/tr><\/tbody><\/table><\/body><\/html>"
          }
       }]
    }
```

Groovy

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def object = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)
def html = object.value[0].body.content
log.info "HTML 1 : " + html //here I am getting html page.
def content = new XmlSlurper( new SAXParser() ).parse( html ) //getting error at this line
```

Expected

I want the key value from the href
<a href="https://abc.xyz123.com?key=GBsG3gBoI4YV+fSfejXCbw6vgG6m4OCU7Czfn3PAKXtxVI9Ex"

Key: `GBsG3gBoI4YV+fSfejXCbw6vgG6m4OCU7Czfn3PAKXtxVI9Ex`

Comment: html usually is not well-formatted xml. you could request from developers to make it well formatted to be able to use xml parser or you could use external library like jsoup to parse html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I used similar Regex-based code to do simple web-crawling:

```
def content = "<lotsoftags..><a href=\"https://abc.xyz123.com?key=GBsG3gBoI4YV+fSfejXCbw6vgG6m4OCU7Czfn3PAKXtxVI9Ex\" style=\"font-family:'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif; font-weight:400; font-size:18pt;\"<lotsoftags..>"

def keys = ( content =~ /<a href="[^"]+[?&]?key=([\w+]+)&?[^"]*"/ ).findAll()*.last()

assert keys[ 0 ] == 'GBsG3gBoI4YV+fSfejXCbw6vgG6m4OCU7Czfn3PAKXtxVI9Ex'
```

Comment: Thanks :) Works Perfectly for this key. If the key has a forward slash in between then it trims the later part. Can you tell me the regular expression to handle this? 
key=Ugidljpi6K6qy5XqsSN1JcR20YhysRAaP5hWEm/ZhgoHNBndWmROa1RDR+LEgKkJ\

Comment: Able to create one that working with all types of keys.......
def key = ( html =~ /(?<=key=).*?(?=")/ )

Comment: `key=([\/\w+]+)` for forward slash should do